# Shifted shapefiles with same coordinate system in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinate-system

I have a strange situation with one of my `GIS` projects. I received from a client three shapefiles in the same coordinate system (*Stereographic 1970 - a projected system*). All three files should align perfectly. This happens only for two of them, the third one is shifted from the rest of the project.
*I`ve tried to apply different methods of converting the coordinate system*, reproject but no success till now.

Apparently, the shapefile that is not overlapping with the other two, is coming from a reconversion of a different coordinate system.
Do you have any solution that might work in `ArcGIS`? Or `Global Mapper`?

Comment: Which methods have you tried?

Comment: This most often happens when somebody defines the shapefile with a coordinate system that differs from what it was actually recorded in. Reprojecting will not fix it. You probably need to start with the original file and use the Define Projection tool to pick the coord sys that was used to record the data. BTW- ArcGIS will project on-the-fly once it is defined correctly.

Comment: Tried to reproject the file in ArcGIS - no success. Tried to define the projection - no success. Tried to erase the prj file and re-write a new one with the correct projection - no success. Tried to spatial adjust the file - no success. If someone had copied the polygons from a file in 3844 coordinate system and then pasted in another file with 31700 coordinate system - can be the source of the shift?